# The given path's format is not supported for decryption (C#)

Tags: c#, encryption, filepath

I am working on modifying https://github.com/alexjwong/file-encrypt-decrypt so that it does not need the openFileDialog but instead I can directly set the file path. I have tried forcing the private String FilePath = ""; to private String FilePath = "C:\Path\To\my\File.txt.des";

When I tried that, I got the error The given path's format is not supported. I then tried using @"C:\Path\To\my\File.txt.des" but got the same error. I decided to try using a openFileDialog. It worked without a hitch.

```
    // Set filter options and filter index.
    openFileDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Encrypted Files (*.des)|*.des";
    openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;

    // Use openFileDialog tool (in designer) to create openFileDialog1
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        FilePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

    this.Invalidate();
```

That is the code for the open file dialog. How could I force the file path on Form load?

Comment: Be aware that the encryption code you have linked is horribly insecure.  Don't use it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up :D

Answer (score -1):

Changed my code to be

```
    FilePath = "C:\\Users\\prefo\\Desktop\\test.txt.des";
    this.Invalidate();
```

and it worked!